# NSIS page with a list of opened browser windows

Tags: browser, installation, nsis

Is there any standard way (or existing plugin) which allows to create a page in NSIS installer package and display there all existing browser windows. Something with the possibility of closing all browsers before proceeding with an installation.

Thanks.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? Do you only care about the big 4 or do you need to detect K-Melon etc?

Comment: I was interested in closing IE, FF, Safari, Opera and Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

The [LockedList plug-in](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/LockedList_plug-in) can display a list of running processes, this is probably your best option. The other alternative would be to look for specific windows classes and then you are on your way into undocumented land...

Comment: Thanks. But it is not what I actually searched. I've already implemented own plugin for this.